# Getting an Error While Displaying SSRS Report in ReportViewer

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I am getting an error while Displaying SSRS Report(.rdl) in Report Viewer.The error is like this..

```
  An error occurred during local report processing.
  The definition of the report 'Main Report' is invalid.
  The report definition is not valid. Details: The report definition has an invalid target            namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition' which      cannot be upgraded...
```

I m New in SSRS Report...so Plz help me.........

Answer (score 2):

It seems like a format versioning issue. Can you view the report properly directly on SSRS (without the control)?

If so, it probably means that you need to upgrade your ReportViewerControl in your application - VS 2010 has version 10 of the control.

If not, it may mean that the RDL uploaded to SSRS isn't the correct version for your server.

**Edit**
You haven't stated whether your app is web or windows - I've assumed web.
What might have happened is that you upgraded your project from VS2008 and it is still referencing V 2008 of the ReportViewer control?

Check your app's web.config

Under `<system.web><compilation><assemblies>`

```
<add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
<add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
```

Under `<system.web><compilation><buildProviders>`

```
<add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
```

And you need to make sure that your web project has a reference to v 10 of `Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common` and `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms`, and it is set to deploy to your bin directory.

**Edit2**

VS2010 uses Ajax - add in a ScriptManager to your page before the ReportViewer control, or just paste in the following:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scmForReportViewer" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Comment: Yes i am creating in 2010....so wat should i do?because i m new in SSRS Report so i cant getting an error...

Comment: sorry after adding in Web.config as u say above i m getting same error...An error occurred during local report processing.
The definition of the report 'Main Report' is invalid.
The report definition is not valid. Details: The report definition has an invalid target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition' which cannot be upgraded.

Comment: Hello as Per u say i had done all change in web.config but now i get an error like The Report Viewer Web Control requires a System.Web.UI.ScriptManager on the web form.